# How to identify unique items within a dataset defined by different attributes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following dataset of items

items:

```
item
i1
i2
i3
i4
```

attributes

```
item | attribute | attr_group
i1     green       color
i2     red         color
i1     fancy       style
i2     cool        style
i4     purple      color
i3     red         color
i1     REF1        refid
i2     REF2        refid
i3     REF2        refid
i4     REF1        refid
```

attribute group names

```
attr | group
a1     color
a2     style
a3     refid
```

articles:

```
article_id | title ..
ref1_1
ref1_2
ref2
```

Now I want to fill table articles with unique items identified by `article_id`. A unique item is defined as an item which has a refid that is either with no attributes or has more then one different color.

e.g. There are two items with ref1 (green and purple), therefore ref1 can not be unique in itself but will have 2 article_ids: ref1_1 and ref1_2.

The items which have ref2 are of the same color, therefore there is only one article_id to be defined.

How could a possible MySQL query look like to select unique items and insert them into the table articles? I can't wrap my head around this any help is greatly appreciated.

My best attempt looks like the following SQL query, however it will only define articles based on ref_id and color, what is missing are the items that have all the same color.

```
/* create unique articles */
INSERT
IGNORE INTO articles (article_id, URL, ref_id, cat_id, dial_id)
SELECT CONCAT ( a.value, '-', a2.value) AS article_id,
       CONCAT ( cs.name_safe, '-', LOWER(ca.attr_de), '-r', a.value) AS URL,
       a.value AS refid,
       cs.ID,
       a2.value AS color_id
FROM `classifieds_attr` a
INNER JOIN classifieds c ON c.ID = a.cl_id
INNER JOIN cat_names_sub cs ON c.cat_id = cs.ID
INNER JOIN `classifieds_attr` a2 ON c.ID = a2.cl_id
AND a2.attr_group_id = 9
INNER JOIN cat_attr ca ON a2.value = ca.attr_id
WHERE a.attr_group_id = 8
  AND cs.cat_main_id = 15
  AND a2.value NOT LIKE 'Invalid:%'
GROUP BY refid,color_id
```

Comment: I don't get the point of the attr column

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the feedback, this is quite a complex task and the difficulty in my eyes lies in the logic where I am stuck and was hoping to get some help or input from more experienced developers. I have added my best shot to the question.

Comment: There are many questions about writing SQL queries to process attribute-value tables like this. You may not be able to find one that directly answers your question, but you should learn the general techniques for using them. Then you apply your programming expertise to come up with a solution to your specific problem. That's programming -- it's a creative process, not "paint by numbers".

Answer (score 0):

Getting the items is not hard:

```
SELECT a.item
FROM attributes a
GROUP BY a.item
HAVING sum(attr_group = 'refid') > 0 AND
       (sum(attr_group = 'refid') = count(*) OR -- only a refid
        min(CASE WHEN attr_group = 'color' THEN attribute END) <>
        max(CASE WHEN attr_gruop = 'color' THEN attribute END)
       );
```

I'm not sure how to turn these into "articles", but this might be what you need.

Comment: Interesting approach. This is however assuming that items are always with the attributes list which is not the case. All items are in table items and only if there are attributes, there will be an entry in table attributes.

Comment: @merlin . . . If they have a `resid`, they have an attribute.  And you require resids.

Comment: You are right, did not think about that.  I tried to adapt your query but the results are not the one I am looking for. How could I illustrate the case better? Is there something like jsfiddle where I can upload some sample data?